# How to call this Delphi function from C#?

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke, marshalling, widestring

i'm having problems calling a delphi function from C# (attempted to read or write protected memory), and was wondering what the correct way of calling the method should be. The Delphi function signature is as follows:

```
procedure methodToCall(
    aFirstParameter: Widestring; 
    var aSecondParameter: Widestring
    ); stdcall;
```

What is the correct way of calling this method from C#?

Comment: Hi, how are you calling this from C#? with DllImport or with COM interoperability? Did you add the reference? Can we see the C# side as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The WideString is compatible with COM BSTR and so the .net marshaller should be able to consume it quite happily:

```
[DllImport(@"test.dll")]
private static extern void methodToCall(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    string aFirstParameter,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    ref string aSecondParameter
);
```

Comment: what would happen if i used [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder firstParameter  ?

Comment: What would be wrong because the Delphi code is written to receive a WideString (aka BSTR) and not an LPStr. I just wrote a DLL to test this and the C# code above works perfectly.

Comment: Have you a source for Delphi WideStrings and BSTR being the same?

Comment: @CodeInChaos It's stated in the [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/String_Types#WideString)